# How do I get all contents from JSON array in jquery. Most simple way

Tags: php, jquery, json

I am using jstree and it generates a JSON array on an external php page.I just need a simple secure way of displaying this data, via jquery or javascript, that I can append css to. I have looked at json2.js etc but there are actually no examples. I have spent three hours today on something that seems so simple.
My array looks like this.

```
[{"attr":{"id":"node_80","rel":"folder"},"data":"TEST","state":"closed"},{"attr":{"id":"node_271","rel":"folder"},"data":"testing","state":""},{"attr":{"id":"node_43","rel":"folder"},"data":"testing3namefield","state":"closed"},{"attr":{"id":"node_270","rel":"folder"},"data":"gagaga","state":""},{"attr":{"id":"node_267","rel":"default"},"data":"yyy","state":""},{"attr":{"id":"node_266","rel":"default"},"data":"my test.txt","state":""},{"attr":{"id":"node_33","rel":"folder"},"data":"azaz","state":"closed"}]
```

Also everything seems to mention security measures, and I dont know what is safe.

Comment: You can use [json-sans-eval](http://code.google.com/p/json-sans-eval/). Which doesn't use `eval`.

Comment: I had a look at that but I still cant find an example of how it works. My JSON script is a url. ie server.php?operation=get_children&id=2. It mentions jsonparse, and I cant find an easy example.

Comment: There is an example on that page? What exactly don't you understand?

Comment: Hi it mentions var myJson = '{ "x": "Hello, World!", "y": [1, 2, 3] }'; Can I use the url as a variable.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the data you provided in your question is the direct (and only) output of your PHP json script.  If so, it is very straightforward.

```
(function() {
    $.getJSON( '/server.php?operation=get_children&id=2', function(data) {
       ​$.each(data, function(key,value) {
           $('body').append('<div>'+value.data+'<br/>'+value.state+'</div><hr/>');
       });​
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I tried that and no success. Am I missing something simple.